# Making the type of a function depend on input

Tags: function, haskell, if-statement, types

So I noticed that after n=20 the factorial function given in LearnYouAHaskell (below) craps out because of the finite work range of the Int type.

```
factorial :: Int -> Int
factorial 0 = 1
factorial n * factorial (n-1)
```

Using `factorial :: Integer -> Integer` fixes the issue nicely, but it brought to mind the question. Supposedly Integer is slightly slower than Int so ideally (and I know I'm pinching pennies here) I'd want my factorial function to only resort to Integer when the input is greater than 20 and retain the `Int->Int` type for the smaller numbers. Seems like there should be an elegant solution for this using if-then-else or guards, but keep running into syntactic pepper (error messages)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can make a hackish solution without dependent types by using either a sum type and growing when needed or delaying the cast to `Integer` till the end in some cases.  I don't expect either solution would perform better than using `Integer` - do not fear the Integer, gmp and mpir are quite good.

The casting solution is something like:

```
selectiveFactorial :: Integer -> Integer
selectiveFactorial i
    | i < 20 = fromIntegral $ factorial (fromIntegral i :: Int)
    | otherwise = factorial i

factorial :: Integral a => a -> a
factorial 0 = 1
factorial n = n * factorial (n - 1)
```

Comment: In GHC we have that [`Integer`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/integer-gmp-1.0.0.0/docs/GHC-Integer-GMP-Internals.html#t:Integer) is exactly a sum type, with small values using a more efficient representation. Hence, adding another sum on top would likely make things worse.

Comment: I'd rather write `selectiveFactorial :: Int -> Integer; selectiveFactorial i | i < 20    = fromIntegral (factorial i) | otherwise = factorial (fromIntegral i)`.

Answer (score 7):

As [Rein Henrichs said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32594907/1477667) you could do these things in a language with dependent types, which Haskell does not (yet, quite) have. In Idris, say, it would look something like

```
factorial : (n : Int) -> if n <= 20 then Int else Integer
factorial n with (n <= 20)
  factorial n | True = thisfactorial n
  factorial n | False = thatfactorial n
```

But how will you *use* this result? Well, you'll need to do the comparison to figure out what type to expect, and when all is said and done, I don't see how you've won anything. For completeness, the use site could look something like this:

```
use : Int -> Integer
use n with (factorial n)
  use n | fn with (n <= 20)
    use n | fn | False = fn
    use n | fn | True = cast fn
```

Note that the order of the `with` clauses is significant! The `fn` binding gets type `if n <= 20 then Int else Integer`; for reasons I don't entirely understand, the `n <= 20` test must be to the right of that in order for the pattern match to affect its type.

Comment: The [same](http://lpaste.net/141109) in Haskell with singletons (works for me only if I replace `:<=` and `%:<=` with `:==` and `%:==`).

Comment: You probably can return `Either Int Integer`, but I guess `Integer` is already `Either Int BigInt` ...

Answer (score 5):

It can't be done. There are things you can do however:

1. Make the type more generic: `factorial :: Num a => a -> a`;
   This allows the  user of your function to decide what runtime penalties he wants to occur vs. what range of numbers is permissible.
2. Use a sum type like `data PossiblyBig = Small Int | Big Integer`, and then have an implementation `instance Num PossiblyBig` that encodes things that fit into `Int` as `Small`, and things that don't fit as `Big`; AFAIK `Integer` already works like that (look up the GMP implementation if you want to know for sure), so this is more of a general example than advice as to what you should do in this particular situation.

Comment: Yes, what you describe is how Integer is implemented already. Any value within the range of `Int` is stored in the same way as `Int`, values outside that range have their data stored in a `ByteArray` field. Adding another layer of the same kind on top probably won't help :)

Answer (score 1):

Making the type of a function depend on its values is exactly what [dependent types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type) are for. Unfortunately, Haskell does not have dependent types so this cannot be done.

Comment: It is worth mentioning the languages that *do* support dependent types, such as [idris](http://www.idris-lang.org/), which is very similar to Haskell.